# Creating a journal from a set of articles

Tags: journal-publishing

How can I create my own journal from a set of articles. Say, every article has a form:

```
\documentclass{myjournalclass}
\title{Article Title}
\author{A.U. Thor1}
\afill{afill to A.U. Thor1}
\author{A.U. Thor2}
\afill{afill to A.U. Thor2}
\begin{document}
\section{One}
Text1
\section{2}
Text 2
\end{document}
```

I need to create a titlepage, a table of contents of the articles and a set of articles themselves. `TOC` should contain a `Article Title` and `authors`. 
How can I collect articles in the journal by `LaTeX`?

Comment: I think, this should be possible with the `combine` package

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8730/producing-a-volume-of-a-journal-in-latex?rq=1 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14074/self-publishing-an-academic-journal?rq=1.