# Write/Read values of the LaTeX commands (like \title, \ author etc) in file using Lua

Tags: luatex, programming, pdfpages, latex3, lua

This problem relate with other my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223336/creating-a-journal-from-a-set-of-articles) . I found a solution with `pdfpages` package thanks to `TX.SX`:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newcommand{\insertpaper}[4]%
           { % Syntax: \insertmydocument{Toc level}{Title}{Subtitle}{File}
             % Requires: tocloft hyperref pdfpages
             \newpage
             \phantomsection
             \cftaddtitleline{toc}{#1}{#2}{\thepage}
             \cftchapterprecistoc{#3}
            \includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={\pagestyle{plain}}]{#4}
           }
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\insertpaper{chapter}{Title o the 1st paper}{A.U. Thor11, A.U. Thor12}{paper1.pdf}
\insertpaper{chapter}{Title o the 2nd paper}{A.U. Thor21, A.U. Thor22}{paper2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

For production conference proceedings, I use `pdfpages`, as shown in example with `LuaLaTeX`. The macro `\insertpaper` adds a titles and authors of the papers in TOC. But for doing this, I manually write a desirable fields (e.g. title and authors) of the PDF. My papers (`PDFs`) also created by `LuaLaTeX` with `scrartcl` class and with `authblk` package for creating `author` and `affiliations`. Now my idea is not to manually fill corresponding fields, but read them from a file. That is, before `paper.tex` should write desirable fields into appropriate file.

It would be nice if the `\insertpaper` would have only one parameter `filename` and information about the required fields read from the appropriate information file.

Thus, I need some help for creation such procedures with `Lua` (desirable) or `LaTeX3` or something else.

I found a some solution how to read the data

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
Title of the page
A.U. Thor1
A.U. Thor2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{luacode}
  function readtxt()
    file = io.open("testdata.dat", "r")
    for line in file:lines() do

      tex.print(line.."\\\\")
    end
  end
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
  \directlua{readtxt()}
\end{document}
```

but I have no idea how to substitude the data into desirable command, `\insertpaper` for example.

Comment: You shouldn't use `tocloft` with KOMA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the suggestion given in my answer to [How to write authors of an article to the file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223512/how-to-write-authors-of-an-article-to-the-file), when you compile `paper1.tex` you'll have a file called `paper1-titleauthors.dat` which will contain something like

```
\thispapertitle{Title of the article}
\thispaperauthor{First Author}
\thispaperauthor{Second Author}
\finishauthors
```

Now you can use the data:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{authblk,tocloft}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\insertpaper}[1]%
  {% #1 is the file name (without extension)
   \clearpage
   \renewcommand\papertitle{}% reinitialize
   \renewcommand\paperauthors{}% reinitialize
   \input{#1-titleauthors.dat}%
   \phantomsection
   \cftaddtitleline{toc}{chapter}{\papertitle\ --- \paperauthors}{\thepage}%
   \includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={\pagestyle{plain}}]{#1}%
}
\newcommand\papertitle{}% initialize
\newcommand\paperauthors{}% initialize
\newcommand{\thispapertitle}[1]{\renewcommand\papertitle{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thispaperauthor}[2]{%
    \g@addto@macro\paperauthors{#1}%
  \ifx#2\finishauthors
    % no more authors
  \else
    \g@addto@macro\paperauthors{, }%
    \expandafter\thispaperauthor % reinsert the swallowed token
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\insertpaper{paper1}
\end{document}
```

This is the contents page you'd get; of course different formattings of the contents line can be defined.

[image]