# How to write totally expanded macro to file (with LaTeX kernel)

Tags: programming, latex-base

I want to write value of the macro `\@authortofile` to a file.  Inside the macro it is another macro which is defined as separator between some words:

```
\def\@separator{\def\@separator{, }}
```

When I try to do this I get in `.dat` file a string:

```
\thispaperauthor{\@separator One\@separator Two\@separator Three}
```

with non expanded  `\@separator`, but I need text like:

```
\thispaperauthor{One, Two, Three}
```

PDF output iat the same time has the required form:
[image]

Here is `MWE`

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@separator{\def\@separator{, }} %---def separator

\def\@authortofile{\@separator One\@separator Two\@separator Three} %def \@authortofile

%---definition of newwrite as \writedatatofile
\newwrite\titleauthorfile
\newcommand\writedatatofile[1]{%
  \immediate\openout\titleauthorfile=#1.dat
  \immediate\write\titleauthorfile{%
     \string\thispapertitle{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@title}}}%
  \immediate\write\titleauthorfile{%
     \string\thispaperauthor{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@authortofile}}}%
  \immediate\write\titleauthorfile{\string\finishauthors}
  \immediate\closeout\titleauthorfile
}
\makeatother
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
\writedatatofile{\jobname}

\makeatletter
\@authortofile
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: You ask about "totally expanded" but `def\@separator{\def\@separator{, }} %---def separator` does not work by expansion, so the question isn't that easy to answer.  It would be possible to define a command that expanded to nothing the first time, or a comma after that but the definition there requires an assignment so is not expandable

Comment: do you really want a space before the comma in the pdf?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, I not need spase before comma, but after.

Comment: looks very weird:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Main problem for me is to substitule \@separator by comma in .dat. Space before comma is just a typo

Comment: It's quite unclear why you wouldn't simply define `\@authortofile` to be `One, Two, Three`. Please be more specific.

Comment: @egreg that is because I do not want coma before the first author tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224449/separator-between-author-names-with-latex-kernel-programming/224454#224454

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\thispapertitle{Title}
\thispaperauthor{One , Two , Three}
\finishauthors
```

From

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@separator{\def\@separator{, }} %---def separator

\def\@authortofile{\@separator One \@separator Two \@separator Three} %def \@authortofile

%---definition of newwrite as \writedatatofile
\newwrite\titleauthorfile
\newcommand\writedatatofile[1]{%
  \immediate\openout\titleauthorfile=#1.dat
  \immediate\write\titleauthorfile{%
     \string\thispapertitle{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@title}}}%
{%
\def\@separator##1\@separator##2{%
\unexpanded{##1}%
\ifx!##2%
\else
, \expandafter\@separator\expandafter##2%
\fi
}%
  \immediate\write\titleauthorfile{%
     \string\thispaperauthor{\@authortofile\@separator!}}%
}%
  \immediate\write\titleauthorfile{\string\finishauthors}%%%
  \immediate\closeout\titleauthorfile
}
\makeatother
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
\writedatatofile{\jobname}

\makeatletter
\@authortofile
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. It's work. Strange construction `\def\@separator##1\@separator##2{%`. I would have guessed about. Where can I read something about programming in LaTeX? Can you recommend some literature?

Comment: @sergiokapone texbook, or free alternative texbytopic

Comment: Newer heard about `texbytopic`. Thanx!

Comment: Just a comment for those (like me) who came here by searching for "write an expanded macro to a file": the key is "\unexpanded\expandafter". I have no idea why, but that's what worked for me.

Comment: @MartinArgerami `\expandafter` expands `\@title` once so revealing its definition then the `\unexpanded` prevents any macros in that definition being further expanded while being written out.