# Write accented characters to file using \write

Tags: expansion, accents, auxiliary-files, write

I am trying to output some information to an auxiliary file using `\write` and among other things I have authors names that often include accented letters. If I use the string explicitly, the accented letters are expanded into TeX commands, but I can solve this by using `\unexpanded`. However, if the string is contained in a variable, and I use `\unexpanded`, I get the name of the variable instead of its content. The command `\unexpanded` works fine again if the variable is a command parameter, for example `#1`.

I don't have an understanding of expansion that is clear enough to sort this out, so any help is appreciated. All I want to do is to write the content of a variable holding a string with accented letters to the text file.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=\jobname_extra.txt
\AtEndDocument{\closeout\file}

\begin{document}
\immediate\write\file{Test 1}                 % works fine
\immediate\write\file{José}                   % expands into TeX code
\immediate\write\file{\unexpanded{José}}      % works fine
\def\mystring{José}
\immediate\write\file{\mystring}              % expands into TeX code
\immediate\write\file{\unexpanded{\mystring}} % outputs \mystring literally
\newcommand{\writeaccented}[1]{
  \immediate\write\file{\unexpanded{#1}}
}
\writeaccented{José}                          % works fine
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I received two answers to use either `\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\mystring}` or `\detokenize\expandafter{\mystring}`. These work fine on the minimal example above, but not on the real example, making me think that the expansion in my case is happening earlier. Here is the new minimal example that is closer to my real case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=\jobname_extra.txt
\AtEndDocument{\closeout\file}

\begin{document}
\def\listofauthors{José Saramago, Luigi Pirandello and Władysław Reymont}
\makeatletter
\StrSubstitute[0]{\listofauthors}{, }{,}[\@cpauthors]
\StrSubstitute[0]{\@cpauthors}{ and }{,}[\@cpauthors]
\@for \@cpauthor:=\@cpauthors\do{%
  \immediate\write\file{<author>\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\@cpauthor}</author>}
}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

EDIT 2: adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` prevents the expansion into TeX commands, but outputs accented letters in ISO-8859 encoding instead of unicode. I tried both with and without the proposed solutions.

EDIT 3: the solution that worked for me is in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390119/36823. Thank you!

Comment: You can try `\protected@write{\file}{}{content}` but that will only be done after a shipout of page.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](//tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=30167&p=102078#p102078)

Comment: 'Of course' `\StrSubstitute` must expand something before it can store it to another macro.

Comment: I adde a more general solution based on the edit

Comment: I won't change my solution because it was giving the result requested before the question was edited multiple times :-(

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\detokenize`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=\jobname_extra.txt
\AtEndDocument{\closeout\file}

\begin{document}

\def\mystring{José}

\immediate\write\file{\detokenize\expandafter{\mystring}} % outputs \mystring literally

\end{document}
```

The contents of the `_extra` file is

```
José
```

The hex dump:

```
0000000 4a 6f 73 c3 a9 0a                              
0000006
```

The UTF-8 representation of `é` is indeed `C3 A9`.

---

A different approach for the more complicated situation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\iow_new:N \g_giampiero_output_stream
\tl_new:N \l__giampiero_write_temp_tl


\AtBeginDocument
 {
   \iow_open:Nn \g_giampiero_output_stream { \c_sys_jobname_str _extra.txt }
 }
\AtEndDocument
 {
  \iow_close:N \g_giampiero_output_stream
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\writeauthors}{sm}
 {% *-version for doing a variable
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \giampiero_writeauthors:V #2
   }
   {
    \giampiero_writeauthors:n { #2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \giampiero_writeauthors:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__giampiero_write_temp_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__giampiero_write_temp_tl { ~and~ } { , }
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__giampiero_write_temp_seq { , } \l__giampiero_write_temp_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__giampiero_write_temp_seq
   {
    \giampiero_write_generic:nn { author } { ##1 }
   }
 }
% This can be used for other similar write operations
\cs_new_protected:Nn \giampiero_write_generic:nn
 {
  \iow_now:Nn \g_giampiero_output_stream { <#1>#2</#1> }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {NnV}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \giampiero_writeauthors:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\listofauthors{José Saramago, Luigi Pirandello and Władysław Reymont}

\begin{document}

\writeauthors{José Saramago, Luigi Pirandello and Władysław Reymont}

\writeauthors*{\listofauthors}

\end{document}
```

Here is the contents of the generated file:

```
<author>José Saramago</author>
<author>Luigi Pirandello</author>
<author>Władysław Reymont</author>
<author>José Saramago</author>
<author>Luigi Pirandello</author>
<author>Władysław Reymont</author>
```

Answer (score 3):

Expansion is a weird beast in TeX ;-)

```
\immediate\write\file{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\mystring}} %
```

will expand the content of `\mystring` first before `\unexpanded` can 'protect' it again.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=\jobname_extra.txt
\AtEndDocument{\closeout\file}

\begin{document}
\immediate\write\file{Test 1}                 % works fine
\immediate\write\file{José}                   % expands into TeX code
\immediate\write\file{\unexpanded{José}}      % works fine
\def\mystring{José}
\immediate\write\file{\mystring}              % expands into TeX code
\immediate\write\file{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\mystring}} % outputs \mystring literally
\newcommand{\writeaccented}[1]{
  \immediate\write\file{\unexpanded{#1}}
}
\writeaccented{José}                          % works fine
\end{document}
```

Output: (%%%% annotation by me)

```
Test 1
Jos\unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {e\global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 19 e\egroup \spacefactor \accent@spacefactor 
José
Jos\unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {e\global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 19 e\egroup \spacefactor \accent@spacefactor 
José%%%%% This one is from \expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\mystring}
José
```

Comment: `\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter` can be shortened to `\unexpanded\expandafter` (i.e. the first one is not needed). Same with `\detokenize`.

Answer (score 2):

## Answer to example with `xstring`

Package `xstring` knows several expansion modes, see section "3.1 Expansion of arguments" of the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/xstring/xstring_doc_en.pdf).

In this case, `\listofauthors` should contain the plain author names as given in the example. Then, mode `\expandarg` just expands the first token, macro `\listofauthors`, but without further expansion.

The example limits the effect of `\expandarg` by a group. It uses `\detokenize` and removes a unnecessary `\expandafter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=\jobname_extra.txt
\AtEndDocument{\closeout\file}

\begin{document}
\def\listofauthors{José Saramago, Luigi Pirandello and Władysław Reymont}
\makeatletter
\begingroup
  \expandarg
  \StrSubstitute[0]{\listofauthors}{, }{,}[\@cpauthors]
  \StrSubstitute[0]{\@cpauthors}{ and }{,}[\@cpauthors]
  \@for \@cpauthor:=\@cpauthors\do{%
    \immediate\write\file{<author>\detokenize\expandafter{\@cpauthor}</author>}
  }
\endgroup
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

File `\jobname_extra.txt`:

```xml
<author>José Saramago</author>
<author>Luigi Pirandello</author>
<author>Władysław Reymont</author>
```