# How to save a macro to a file, unexpanded?

Tags: write, detokenize

I want this to work, but it doesn't:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\hello{Hello, \LaTeX!}
\newwrite\foo
\immediate\openout\foo foo.tex
\immediate\write\foo{\hello}
\immediate\closeout\foo
\end{document}
```

I expect to see this in the `foo.tex` file:

```
Hello, \LaTeX!
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Very similar question: [expansion - Write accented characters to file using \write - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390098/write-accented-characters-to-file-using-write) (that one is for _strings_ but works here as well)

Comment: `\newcommand\hello{Hello, \string\LaTeX!}` works for \write, but also prevents expansion when used in text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\hello{Hello, \LaTeX!}
\newwrite\foo
\immediate\openout\foo foo.tex
\immediate\write\foo{\unexpanded\expandafter{\hello}} % documentation of `\unexpanded` is in texdoc etex_man
%\immediate\write\foo{\detokenize\expandafter{\hello}} % this is an alternative, I believe it's slower than the above, although I didn't benchmark
\immediate\closeout\foo
\end{document}
```

although the actual issue here is: `\LaTeX` command is [robust](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/250119), but it's old-style robust. So an alternative fix (identical in this case but hopefully you can see what's the difference) is

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\hello{Hello, \LaTeX!}
\newwrite\foo
\immediate\openout\foo foo.tex
\makeatletter
\set@display@protect % see source2e...
\immediate\write\foo{\hello}
\restore@protect
\makeatother
\immediate\closeout\foo
\end{document}
```

there's `\protected@write` but no analogous `\immediate@protected@write` as far as I can see.

(or you can copy the `\protected@iwrite` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110885/250119.

Similar question: [Storing environment arguments by \immediate\write](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163686/250119)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expl3` for the job, which also allows to have a sort of namespace for your text variables.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\vardef}{mm}
 {% #1 = symbolic name, #2 = text
  \tl_clear_new:c { l_yegor_var_#1_tl }
  \tl_set:cn { l_yegor_var_#1_tl } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\varwrite}{mm}
 {% #1 = symbolic name, #2 = file
  \iow_open:Nn \g_yegor_var_outfile_iow { #2 }
  \iow_now:Nv \g_yegor_var_outfile_iow { l_yegor_var_#1_tl }
  \iow_close:N \g_yegor_var_outfile_iow
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\varuse}{m}
 {
  \tl_use:c { l_yegor_var_#1_tl }
 }

\iow_new:N \g_yegor_var_outfile_iow
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_now:Nn { Nv }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\vardef{foo}{Hello, \LaTeX!}

\varwrite{foo}{\jobname.txt}

\end{document}
```

The file written out will contain

```
Hello, \LaTeX !
```

The space before the exclamation mark should be of no concern (it follows a control sequence name, so it will be ignored by TeX).