# PDF as a data container

Tags: hyperref, pdf, package-options

### Inserting data about article to the PDF

It is possible to pass title and author of the article to the appropriate `hyperref` package options? I want to be the values of `\title` - `Title of the article` and `\author` - `A.U. Thor` automatically assigned to `pdftitle`  and `pdfauthor`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
    linkcolor  = red, %Colour of internal links
    citecolor  = green, %Colour of citations
    bookmarks,
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    unicode,
    linktoc = all,
    hypertexnames=false,
    pdftitle={Title of the article},
    pdfauthor={A.U. Thor}]{hyperref}
%opening
\title{Title of the article}
\author{A.U. Thor}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\section{One}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

### Extracting data from PDF

I have another question, which is relate to this [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223471/write-read-values-of-the-latex-commands-like-title-author-etc-in-file-usin). In the referred question, the `.tex` file reads the data about title and authors from external `.dat`-file and then use it for some purposes (creating TOC, for example).
Now I want to use only  `.pdf` as a data container.
Thus, how it is possible to extract appropriate fields from `PDF` file to the `LaTeX` using `pdfpages` package?

[image]

Comment: To the first question, unless you are doing batch work, i don't see why one would go into the trouble of redefining `author` and `title`. You would need to assure that hyperref is loaded an all that.

Comment: What do you mean with the second question? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Johannes_B I has added some explanation in the question. Hope, it will become a little clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delay setting the options when `\@title` and `\@author` have been set:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
    linkcolor  = red, %Colour of internal links
    citecolor  = green, %Colour of citations
    bookmarks,
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    unicode,
    linktoc = all,
    hypertexnames=false,
]{hyperref}
%opening
\title{Title of the article}
\author{A. U. Thor}

\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle=\@title,
  pdfauthor=\@author,
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\maketitle


\section{One}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx! Do you know how to extract this data from the pdf using `pdfpages`. This related with your answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223471/write-read-values-of-the-latex-commands-like-title-author-etc-in-file-usin I want to do the same but without using any additional dat-files, but only pdf as a data container. It seems to me, it will be more economical.

Comment: You can use a program such as `pdfinfo`.