# Create 1-TeX-file version of PythonTeX document

Tags: journal-publishing, journal, pythontex

I use PythonTeX for a number of my articles, yet a number of journals request a single `.tex` file which they can compile with what I assume is just texlive and a bunch of packages.

The problem being that they don't have PythonTeX.
The way I understand it, however, PythonTeX generates a bunch of PGF and PNG figures, which are then static unless it is re-run.
I also see that PythonTeX does not re-run any Python code if I do just recompile the document without editing any of the code.

Is there any way to use the trace files generated by pdflatex and PythonTeX upon compilation to create a document which will compile without PythonTeX and simply based on the static figures I can distribute to them?

I have tried `arlatex` based on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14074/self-publishing-an-academic-journal) but it fails for the PythonTeX elements (be they figures or text).

Answer (score 1):

PythonTeX comes with `depythontex` that, according to section 5 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pythontex/pythontex.pdf),

> can convert a PythonTEX document into a plain LATEX document

You need to

1. Turn on the package option `depythontex`
2. Run the `depythontex.py` script
3. Compile the `depythontex` file