# LaTeX - Assistance Publishing a Mathematical Theorem

Tags: math-mode, journal-publishing

I have a mathematical theorem written in pencil on paper. I am using a handheld device to use the internet.

On this webpage - http://annals.math.princeton.edu/submission-guidelines - are the high requirements of the modern world for the publication of a math paper. I have hundreds of handwritten pages of mathematical work, but what I need to publish should be only ten pages or so.

Proving Legendre's conjecture took a lot of work. Verifying the proof took a lot of work. Putting the proof into text will be a lot of work, for my handwritten papers have more numbers than words, and the drawings have to be explained. Publishing the proof of Legendre's conjecture in a refereed mathematics publication of worldwide repute would allow other mathematicians to read it at their convenience and verify it for themselves and, most importantly, make use of the other results which follow from the proof technique.

From the start, through the process, to the finish is the way to go. I need assistance getting started.

Comment: Independent of the details of the material, sounds like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner is the place to start to me.

Comment: @JosephWright: Right!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Well, first, I agree with what @Joseph said. Second, there is a part of your post that is not about LaTeX at all: How to squeeze your thoughts and proofs into 10 pages. This is certainly off-topic here. Nevertheless, I think that you simply need to choose a journal that accepts papers longer than 10 pages. As well, AFAIK, there are even journals willing to review a handwritten paper, as long as it's completely clear and nicely written.

Comment: If the link covers what you need then I'll mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Would it be easy to convert a document from pdf to LaTeX?

Comment: Perhaps an example scanned page would at least help the community to get an idea what you want to accomplish.

Comment: This one is pretty informative too: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8730/producing-a-volume-of-a-journal-in-latex?rq=1

Comment: You ask, "Would it be easy to convert a document from pdf to LaTeX?" The answer is, sadly, NO. This is especially true if the file contains math material, drawings, and tables -- which would likely seem to be the case for your project.

Comment: And whether it is text or maths, the answer is even more NO if we are talking about a PDF which is the result of scanning handwritten pages. Before you put a great deal of time into this, have you run your proof by some other mathematicians? They would also be able to advise you on the most appropriate journals.

Comment: Catch 22. To run a proof by other mathematicians, the proof should be typed up. I will have to talk with my neighbors to start the process of preparing the proof for presentation. I never knew of LaTeX before I saw the Annals of Mathematics webpage. I do want to use it eventually.