# What software can be used to publish an internal technical journal for my company?

Tags: lyx, templates, document-classes, journal-publishing

I'm in the engineering department of a young company, and we're playing with the idea of starting an internal technical journal.  I've found LyX to be extremely powerful for writing papers, and have been making pretty good use of the RevTeX4-1 template.  However, I haven't discovered an easy way to join multiple such articles into a single end document.

My question is this: Is there any software (open source preferred, but commercial would be a possibility for us) which would make the process simple, or would my best bet be to just dive into LyX template and LaTeX document class creation and roll my own? Or maybe use a pure LaTeX editor for the merge, and reserve LyX for individual article creation?

I should mention that it might be feasible to simply output each individual article to PDF then merge them in Acrobat (we have pro version), but then I wouldn't have the advantage of automatically generated TOCs, etc.  Also, it would be nice to have a template for a journal in its entirety, so we can get a better idea of best practices, rather than just winging it.

Damn it, Jim, I'm a Physicist, not an Editor!

Comment: I think reading some basic introductory material and then some more advanced stuff and creating your own document class might be worth it. Few days invested in reading and hacking and something quite good can be the result. For specialised questions, you can come here and ask.

Comment: i'd go with the "separate pdf articles" and a bunch of scripts (perl or similar) to extract the toc material from the latex files and build the issues separately.  if the content of the articles is at all diverse, there's the likelihood of different, possibly incompatible, packages being used, and trying to combine files under those circumstances is a nightmare.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The OP states it's about an internal journal for one company; it seems to me that deciding on a common structure and editing the final result as one TeX file would be possible.  It may be hard to stay on this course as the company grows or external contributors are added, but I'd still give it a try.

Comment: @ArthurReutenauer -- fair enough.  and definitely worth considering.  just needs proper examination up front to make sure the needs are "narrow" enough for a "unitized" approach to work.

Comment: +1 for "Damn it, Jim, I'm a Physicist, not an Editor!"

Comment: Are there any examples of scripts such as you mention, Barb, for extracting TOC content?

Comment: @barbarabeeton, a set of scripts could be doable.  Do you know if there are any examples online, or perhaps a tutorial somewhere which is focused on building them?

If I were to go the route of combining pdfs after creation, how would I go about ensuring that page numbers for each article were correct (i.e. sequential rather than just every article starting at page 1)?

Comment: @TraxusIV -- unfortunately, i don't know of any "public" examples or tutorials, although some may exist.  (i'll look around.)  this is the approach taken by the ams.  however, the whole production system is quite tailored to local requirements (i hesitate to say "unique"), and interacts with an idiosyncratic database, in which publication information (author names, vol/iss/pgnos, etc.) is stored.  the top matter is highly structured (see `amsart.cls`), and references are in `amsrefs` form within each document file, so amenable to extraction to html for presentation on web pages.

Comment: @TraxusIV -- i've just been reminded of an eariler answer of mine (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8748/579) on a similar subject.  you may already have discovered it.  it gives a few more details about the ams production procedures, though nothing that is usable code.

Comment: I did come across that previous answer.  The big challenge I see is how to extract the page numbers from latex files.  If I write a small program (in python, for example) to scan a directory for latex files, I can pull the title of each file out, but my understanding is that the number of pages each article will take up is indeterminate until it's compiled into dvi or pdf?  How can that be gleaned?

Comment: Is there any news here?